# Limits at infinity where $f(x)$ is unbounded

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine $\lim\limits_{x→0^+}\ln x$.

I am able to solve this numerically i.e. by banging numbers into a calculator, but I am unable to comprehend it analytically as the source recommends:

"
We could approach this analytically by observing that $y=\ln x$ is the inverse of $y=e^x$.

Since $\lim\limits_{x→−∞} e^x=0$,
we know that $\lim\limits_{x→0^+} \ln x=−∞$
"

Could someone please make expand upon this to make it clear to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that they mean:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln(x) = \lim_{e^x \to 0^+} \ln(e^x) = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \ln(e^x) = \lim_{x \to - \infty} x = - \infty$$